# Save a string vector as a .sas file (or any custom extension)

Tags: matlab

I have a large string vector that contains SAS code that I generate using Matlab.  Is there a way to save/export said string as a file with the .sas extension?

Comment: Saving it with .sas extension might not make it a legit .sas file, i.e. the extension does not ensure the format.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I think the string contains the code from a language called sas.

Comment: I know that .sas7bdat files have proprietary format, thus my comment which might apply to simple .sas as well.

Comment: @OlegKomarov I see, sorry, didn't know about that.

Comment: I'd like to try any way.  Any tips on how I might go about that?

Comment: By the way, I'm able to open .sas files in Notepad (and I can write SAS code in Notepad and then change the extension to .sas and they work).

Comment: just use "save"? -> [save-function-doc](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/save.html)